# Prevent Bot Spamming - Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-design

I am about to launch an app and want to prevent bots from creating multiple posts in fractions of a second.

Here are my current security rules:

```json
 "new_groups": {
       ".write": "auth.uid != null",
       ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    },
```

This is the structure of my database regarding groups:

```
new_groups
    group1
    group2
    group3
        items
            item1
                created_timestamp
                authorId
            item2
                created_timestamp
                authorId
            item3
                created_timestamp
                authorId
```

My new rules should pass the following requirements:

1. A user can only write if authenticated
2. A user can only post an item to the `items` directory within a group **once per second**. In other words, the difference in the timestamps between the last item created with `authorId == auth.uid` should be >=1000.
3. A user can bulk delete AND update as many items as they want in any timeframe, there should be no restrictions to deleting/updating data except authentication.

An alternative to using timestamps on the created items would be to track when the user last wrote to the DB (in general) but I understand that is not possible with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the potential solution you can try,

```
{
  "rules": {
    "new_groups": {
      ".write": "auth.uid != null",
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
      "$group_id": {
        "items": {
          "$item_id": {
            ".write": "
              auth.uid != null &&
              (!data.exists() || (newData.child('authorId').val() == auth.uid && newData.child('created_timestamp').val() - data.child('created_timestamp').val() >= 1000))
            ",
            ".read": "auth.uid != null",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, here I'm checking is it current user matches user id and then there last post is greater than 1000.

Comment: So here you are dinamically checking to see if any other item with that author id has been created in the last second?